Identify this movie about a psychiatrist and a woman in a mental hospital
I saw this movie several years ago, but I can't find it anymore since it is not a very well known movie. The movie was a Mystery/Thriller:

The protagonist was a psychiatrist or a doctor who works with mentally ill people. A woman connects with him and ask him to come to I think it was Spain to help her sister who is diagnosed with schizophrenia. 
This "psychiatrist/doctor" is actually married, but his wife (according to him) has left him without telling him nothing. (I am saying this because at the end he remembers that he killed her).
He goes there and talks with the patient. She has 3 personalities (She changes eye color when switching between personalities and she talks other languages that she doesn't know like Japanese/Chinese, and one of her personalities smoke cigarettes). 
The "psychiatrist/doctor" acknowledges that her personalities are murder victims. Their spirits have settled in her body. 
At the end he finds that he killed the girls who are her personalities and his wife too. 
I think the movie has a lesson like in "Hide and Seek". That the psychiatrist for so many years has worked with mentally ill people that he finally became like them.
I remember that in the mental hospital the doctors talked Spanish or a similar language. 


Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in?  Descriptions or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

This is The Lost with Armand Assante from 2009. From Rotten Tomatoes:

Kevin is an American psychiatrist, who has become a successful best seller writer. During the promotion of his latest book he is visited by and old patient's sister. She asks him to go back to Barcelona to reopen the case of her sister who has been confined in a mental institution in an almost catatonic state since Kevin diagnosed her three years ago. His return to the city where he used to work and live will bring back the shadows of a past his own mind had suppressed.

The sister with multiple personalities whose eyes change color, the twist where the protagonist killed all those women (including his wife), taking place in Spain, it's all there. Here's the trailer:



